# if文の書き方。

Tags: python, python3

あらかじめ部品名をリスト化
リストと入力した部品名を照合→対応した加工寸法表示するというプログラムを作ってみました。

ただこれでは部品名が増えるたびに、elif を追加することになります。部品名は数十種類になりそうなのでもっと短縮してコードを書く方法はないでしょうか？？

```
material = ["部品A","部品B","部品C", "部品D"] #7mm,8mm,9mm,10mmと仮定する
x = input()

if material[0] == x: #　xは読み込んだ値
    print("7mm")
elif material[1] == x:
    print("8mm")
elif material[2] == x:
    print("9mm")
elif material[3] == x:
    print("10mm")
    ・
    ・
    ・
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

キーと値で対となる「ディクショナリ」を定義しておき、そこから入力した内容（キー）に一致する値を出力するのが良さそうです（単純なやり方ならif文無しでも書けてしまいそうですが）。

```
material = {"部品A":"7mm", "部品B":"8mm", "部品C":"9mm", "部品D":"10mm"}
x = input()

print(material.get(x, 'Not Found'))
```

参考：
https://www.python-izm.com/basic/dict/

Comment: ありがとうございました！。今回はリストより辞書の方が綺麗にかけるようですね。次のステップはx = input() の部分をエクセルデータから読みだしたセルの値にし、より目指すプログラムに近づけていこうと思います。再勉強しますがまた躓いたらよろしくお願いします。